# Salesforce SOAP API Service Endpoints

Tags: soap, salesforce

When making a web-service call to one of the SOAP APIs in salesforce.com, each API has a service endpoint that follows the same general format: 
https://yourinstance.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/34.0. Where the letter after Soap/ varies depending on the API you want to use as follows:

```
// c - Enterprise
// u - Partner
// s - Apex
// T - Tooling
// o - ???????
// m - Metadata
```

The first three had seemed very arbitrary since the words don't contain the letter that represents them, but once I had them written down in this order, it got me wondering, is this an acronym?

And if so, is there an /o/ API?

Comment: Your asking if a SOAP API exists that would allow the identifiers to spell out an arbitrary word? That's a bit random isn't it?

Comment: Either that or do you know of another explanation on why Enterprise = c, Partner = u, and Apex = s